# Python: can't open file 'scripts/setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, bash, macos, virtual-environment

I am using some instructions from here, to install and run python scripts/setup.py, to start a server for a project I am working on:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/11IPqZcDcLTd2mtYaR5ONpDxFgL9Y1nMNTDvEarST8Wk/edit#

Specifically, I am using these commands (I am running this on macOS, terminal):

```
Option 2: Use Virtual Environment:
git clone http://github.com/wroscoe/donkey.git
virtualenv -p python3 donkey_env
source donkey_env/bin/activate
pip install -e donkey[server]
cd donkey
python scripts/setup.py
python scripts/serve.py
```

I have followed them line by line but am getting, this error:

`python: can't open file 'scripts/setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

It seems that the setup.py file is in the donkey folder, so I have no idea why it is not able to run or find it.

Additionally, I have googled the web for hours searching for an answer and have not come across anything. Any guidance, advice, or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this:

python setup.py   

there is no script directory in the package.

Comment: @Ranjeet It returns this: File "setup.py", line 1
    wfrom setuptools import setup, find_packages
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I am guessing there is an actual problem with the file. If so is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Haye you tried this:git clone https://github.com/wroscoe/donkey donkeycar
pip install -e donkeycar

Comment: Did you notice the bright red text in the opening sentence of the instructions? It reads "**THESE ARE OLD INSTRUCTIONS… see [docs.donkeycar.com](https://docs.donkeycar.com) for updated instructions.**". Unless you are specifically going the old way, then perhaps go the route of the new...

Comment: @l'L'l When I try to use the prebuilt zipped image, do I do that on the raspberry pi? If so where is the "Startup Disk Creator"?

Comment: @josh: "Startup Disk Creator" is a debian utility. Since you are on Mac you would need something similar I presume, maybe [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) perhaps? no clue, sorry.

Comment: @l'L'l So I would just need a disk converter and then put that on an sd card which will go to the raspberry pi?? Additionally, it says to Setup the Pi's WiFi for first boot. Do I just drag the file that I have created onto the sd card? Let me know as soon as you get a chance.